# Expected values of balls at position equal to ball number

Tags: probability, summation, permutations, solution-verification

This is the question that I'm trying to solve

> Balls are drawn one after the other uniformly at random without replacement from a set of eight balls numbered 1,2,...,8 until all balls drawn what is expected number of balls whose value matched their ordinality (i.e their position in the order in which balls were drawn)

I came up with this solution

> Let P(1) be the probability of drawing 1st ball at 1st draw, clearly
> $P(1) = \frac{1}{8}$
>
> Similarly $P(2) = \frac{7}{8}\times\frac{1}{8}=\frac{7}{8^2}$
>
> & $P(3) =
> > \frac{7}{8}\times\frac{6}{8}\times\frac{1}{8}=\frac{7\times6}{8^2}$
>
> It can be seen that, the probability of drawing ith ball at ith draw
> is $P(i) = \frac{^7P_{i-1}}{8^i}$
>
> The expected number of balls whose value match their position =
> $\sum^8_{i=1}i\times P(i)$
>
> $ \sum^8_{i=1}i\times\frac{^7P_{i-1}}{8^i}$,

Which when calculated comes out to be 1.

Is this solution correct? Instead of calculating by hand, i wrote this python script,

```
def fact(n):
    f = 1
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        f *= i
    return f

def P(n, r):
    return fact(n) / fact(n - r)

def foo(n):
    sum = 0    
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        sum += i * P(n-1, i - 1) * (n**(n-i))
    return sum/n**n
    
for i in range(1, 15):
    print(i, foo(i)) # always prints 1.0
```

To my surprise it gave the answer 1 despite the number of balls n, which is why I think there must be some mistake or is $\sum_{i=1}^{n}i\times\frac{^{n-1}P_{i-1}}{n^i} = 1$ some identity I'm unaware of.
Even if my solution is correct it seems over complicated and hard to compute for such a simple problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the linearity of expectation.

Expectation is linear even when the random variables are not independent.

Let $X$ be an indicator random variable such that $X_i$ assumes a value of $1$ if number $i$ is drawn on the $i^{th}$ draw, and $0$ otherwise.

Then $\mathbb{E}(X_i) = P(X_i) = \frac 1 8$

and $\mathbb{E}(X) = \Sigma\mathbb{E}(X_i) = 8\cdot \frac 1 8  = 1$

This also explains why you got the answer of $1$ for $n$ numbers, too.

Comment: >Each number has a probability of $\frac{1}{8}$ of being in its proper place,
What do you mean by that?

Comment: Number $3$, say, has an equal probability of being drawn  at any of the 8 draws, so probability it is the third to be drawn is $\frac 1 8 $

Comment: Thanks I got it now

Comment: I am changing a few lines to make the explanation more formal.